# Tile before or after fitting bathtub

Tags: bathroom, tiling

I am part way through completely refitting my bathroom and keep debating what the best approach is regarding tiling around the bathtub.

Most videos online suggest that you either fit the bath or at least mark on the wall and fit some wood to tile up from. I appreciate that this will save on cost but are there any other benefits to doing it this way over tiling the full wall? Could the tile sitting further out above the bath help to prevent water from sitting on the edge of the tub (see below)?

```
Tile above bath.       Tile full wall

..|                    ..|
..|                    ..|
---                    ..|---
   |                   ..|   |
   |                   ..|   |
```

I don't mind spending more money on tiles if it saves on cutting, etc. So long as it is either the better option or is not the worst option :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way sealing is the issue.

Then in the future when you get rid of the bath for an open shower you have to get more tiles... unless you purchase sufficient now... which means you may as well fit them... but will they look “cleaner” since they were hidden?

Comment: I am not sure I want to consider ever replacing the bath given the amount of effort going in now :). You make a very good point though! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you tile up to the bath you can use a seal like this that fits underneath the tile and provides a substantial lip that sits over the edge of the bath. The back of the strip is  sandwiched between the wall and tile with tile adhesive and the lip is usually filled with silicone sealant that sticks to the rim of the bath or shower tray. The advantage is that water is diverted into the bath regardless of the condition of the sealant. Some of them have a flexible edge as an extra seal.

[image: Homelux Bath Seal Pro]